# CSS fix make object stay same position as another

Tags: css, class, position

I have 2 objects/classes (obj1, obj2) and I want that obj2 has the same position as obj1 (I have a responsive code so I can't simply copy and paste the CSS).

When I come over a certain screen width obj2 won't stay at the same position like obj1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `height: auto` and `width:` in % for each element. But you better show the example.

Comment: its not the widht or the height it is the position I had a left margin of 15% but when the screen res goes over 1930px it just crashes and it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I suppose, that wrapping element of these 2 objects become too small when you reach 1930px or higher. Try to set the fix width for this element (try `max-width`). Or try to set `position: absolute` for these 2 objects and `postition: relativ`e for wrapping element. Oterwise I don´t have any idea. Maybe there is something wrong with this `margin: %`

Comment: I have a question, can you make in css something like go from "margin-left: 15%;" to "margin-left:34%;" with screen resolution?

so : 
@media only screen and (min-width: 1931px) and (max-width: 3840px){

...
}

Comment: I mean I would need something like this (maybe js):

var i = 15;
if screen width (1930px) then margin: 0 0 0 i%;
if screen width (1931px) then i += 0.01;
...

Comment: Yes, using @media queries as you wrote: `@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 978px) {margin: 20%;}`

Comment: You need to enlarge margin every pixel? Like, now I have 1900px and margin is 50px. Now I have 1901px and margin is 51px?

Comment: excatly something like this I think would help:
    var i, j;
    i= 15;
    j = 1930;
    for(screen.width == j px){
    @margin-left:i%;
    i += 0.01;
    j++;
    }

Comment: I would recommned you to solve it by CSS styles rather than using jQuery. If you want to help with js. try to ask somebody else. I would be also interested in solving this problem.

Comment: I want to solve it in css but I have truely no clue how to. The margin of this element seems to freak out after reaching 1930px screen size.